# can't export async function with puppeteer

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, export, puppeteer

How can I export an async function (using puppeteer)?

Comment: trying to get this to another file in an express route

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```js
// in get-data.js

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function getData() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  // ...
  return data;
}

module.exports = {
  getData,
};
```

```js
// in main.js

const { getData } = require('./get-data.js');

(async function main() {
  try {
    const data = await getData();
    console.log(data);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't(